# how to get cart content of second shop in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I have a multistore enable in my Prestashop, I would like to access the cart of the second shop in the first shop. How can I achieve this?

I can get the content of the cart in the current shop using the code below:

```
$this->context->cart
```

but how to access the cart of the second shop which is not in the current context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible with Prestashop classes / methods as **Context** object is related to the current shop.

Isn't using the built-in shared carts between the same shop group a chance ?
I know it's buggy, but it should work as long the two shops are in the same domain.

Otherwise I think you can perform a DB query directly on the **ps_cart_product** table (maybe joined with **ps_cart** to retrieve the **id_customer**) since it contains the **id_shop** row.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best approach ..
There may be completely different products in the other shop, so the cart cannot be valid either.

But if you know the cart_id and the shop_id, you can perform a DB query

```
$query = new DbQuery();
    $query->select('*');
    $query->from('cart');
    $query->where("id_cart= {$cartID}");
    $query->where("id_shop= {$shopID}");
    $result = Db::getInstance()->executeS($query);
```